# Apache reverse proxy not working like expected

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

Ok, I'm feeling a bit stupid about this.

I'm trying to setup a simple Apache reverse proxy setup and I'm hitting a wall. I've had this setup working in the past, but now I just don't see whats going wrong. Heres the setup:

```
Listen 4050

ServerName lb-test
DocumentRoot /www/app

ProxyRequests Off

Header add Set-Cookie "BALANCEID=hej.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/;" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED

<Proxy balancer://cluster>
    BalancerMember http://appserver1:4050 route=appserver1
    BalancerMember http://appserver2:4050 route=appserver2
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://cluster/ stickysession=BALANCEID
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://cluster/

<Location /balancer-manager>
    SetHandler balancer-manager

    Order deny,allow
    Deny from None
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

I can see in the log with debug turned on that requests are being routed to a balancer member, but what is also happening is that the proxy host url is also being inserted into the header.

From the lb host: curl -I localhost

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2012 17:33:18 GMT
Server: thin 1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Via: 1.1 appserver2:4050
Via: 1.1 lb-test
Set-Cookie: BALANCEID=hej.appserver2; path=/;
```

As you can see both hosts are in the header, which is breaking the application. I would think that hitting localhost:80 would not trigger mod_proxy, right? If I hit localhost:4050,  the same thing happens. Anyone know whats going on?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify how the application is breaking due to `Via` headers?  Or is it the `Host` header on the request that's causing problems?

Comment: Its probably the host header. Its passing http://lb-test, appserver2:4050 through to the application.

Comment: It should just be sending `appserver2:4050`, the multi-header format isn't allowed for `Host`.  In any case, Tom's answer should be what you need.

Comment: I tried that, same problem. Response headers still have: `Via 1.1 appserver2:4050, 1.1 lb-test:4050` when i hit `http://lb-test:4050/`

Comment: Can you capture a request with `tcpdump` between the proxy and the backend server?  Making guesses at the request header fields is a poor substitute for being able to actually see them.

Comment: Sure. I fired up tcpdump on the proxy host and ran the client application thats configured to use it. [dumpfile](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6783427/dump.out)

Comment: `tcpdump` truncates packets by default, so data beyond the headers plus a little smidge of packet content isn't visible; add `-s 0` to your `tcpdump` command.

Comment: New tcpdump output [newdump](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6783427/dump.out)

Comment: Hmm.  Seems that there's a `ProxyVia On` directive in your config somewhere?  It defaults to off, but it's definitely on - Apache added it in the proxy connection's request header.

Comment: looks like that did the trick. thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 2):

you should set;

`ProxyPreserveHost On`

in your vhost configuration